# Java:Local variable may not have been initialized?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, while-loop, boolean

Problem: Write a program that reads a list of real numbers.  After the program ends it should print out only the unique numbers.  That is, only numbers that appear once in the list.  If there are more than 50 unique numbers on the list, then you should only print the first 50.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Hmwk {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input=new Scanner (new File ("input.txt"));
        int n = 0;
        final int MAX_SIZE = 50;
        double[] numbersArray;
        while (input.hasNextDouble() && n<MAX_SIZE){
            double in = input.nextDouble();
            if (inList(in,numbersArray))
                numbersArray[n]=in;
                n++;

        }
        printReport(numbersArray);
    }


    public static boolean inList(double number, double[] list){
        for (double i : list) {
            if (i == number){
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
    }

    public static void printReport(double[] list) {
        System.out.printf("The unique numbers were", Arrays.toString(list));
    }

}
```

I'm getting errors saying that numbersArray may not have been initialized. I'm also getting an error saying that my boolean method inList must return a type boolean which confuses me because I have two options of returning true or false. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, your variable

```
double[] numbersArray;
```

is not initialized, just declared. You can initialize it as:

```
double[] numbersArray = new double[MAX_SIZE];
```

---

After your comment:

> It prints out "The unique numbers were" but thats it, no unique numbers

You're using

```
System.out.printf("The unique numbers were",Arrays.toString(list));
```

Two options:

1. Send a `String` parameter using `%s` where you want/need to print the array as string:

   ```
   System.out.printf("The unique numbers were %s.",Arrays.toString(list));
   ```
2. Use `System.out.println`

   ```
   System.out.println("The unique numbers were " + Arrays.toString(list));
   ```

Comment: @user102817 you're welcome. Please do not forget to mark the post that helped you most as the answer.

Comment: For some reason its not printing out anything? Could you help? It prints out "The unique numbers were" but thats it, no unique numbers? Not sure where its messing up

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input=new Scanner (new File ("input.txt"));
        int n = 0;
        final int MAX_SIZE = 50;
        double[] numbersArray; // local variable are initialized at time of declaration
        while (input.hasNextDouble() && n<MAX_SIZE){
            double in = input.nextDouble();
            if (inList(in,numbersArray))
                numbersArray[n]=in;
                n++;

        }
        printReport(numbersArray);
    }
```

you have to initialize it like

```
double[] numbersArray = new double[SIZE];
```

Comment: *local variable are initialized at time of declaration* this is wrong. Class fields are initialized when creating a new instance of the class, with its default value e.g. `class Foo { double[] numbersArray; }`, and the default value of `numbersArray` field will be `null`.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza instance variables in the class are assigned with default value when the object is created not the local variables

Comment: I'm just commenting about the comment next to `double[] numbersArray;`, which is misleading.

Comment: No it is not, it is wrong. The variable is just defined, not initialized. Inside a method, you should always initialize your variables manually before using them. Just note that the comment there is misleading or leads to confusion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46780/discussion-between-luiggi-mendoza-and-girishlalwani2010)

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you are not account for the fact that you might not end up inside the loop(s).

in your 1st case:

```
double[] numbersArray;
while (input.hasNextDouble() && n<MAX_SIZE){
    double in = input.nextDouble();
    if (inList(in,numbersArray))
        numbersArray[n]=in;
        n++;

}
```

what if, input does not have double from the get go? if that is the case your `numbersArray` never initialized. Though in more general terms even if there is a double not initializing your `numbersArray` will cause an exception.

in your second case:

```
for (double i : list)
    {
        if (i == number){
            return false;
    }
        else
            return true;
}
```

if list is empty, then there is no return statement to return from.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you need to initialize numbersArray as shown:

double[] numbersArray = new double[100]; //100 can be replaced with any integer, such as 50, 67, 62152, etc.

Try rewriting inList like this:

```
public static boolean inList(double number, double[] list){
    for (double i : list)
        {
            if (i == number){
                return false;
            }
    }
    return true;
}
```